# existence of neighbor of linear transformation T such that...

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I want to show if a linear transformation $T$ has rank $k$ then there exist $\delta$ such that the open ball centered at $T$ with radius $\delta$ contains only linear transformations that has rank greater than or equal to k

Comment: Mathematical expressions can be posted using [MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and $\LaTeX$.

Comment: What metric are you using?

Comment: I am using the metric sup ｛｜Tv｜/｜v｜ for every v in Rm｝

Comment: @hardmath said to you "Mathematical expressions can be posted using MathJax and $\LaTeX$". On the other hand, what metric are you using for $\mathbb{R}^m$

Comment: Ok. Just euclidean metric

Comment: Finally, what does it means the last line? "has rank greater than or equal to $T$". $T$ is not a number.

Comment: What are you using for the domain and range of these linear transformations?

Comment: Apologize for the ambiguity. Last letter is k. The domain and range of the linear transformations are $R^n$ and $R^m$.

Comment: Then it's $v\in R^n$ in your comment above, not $R^m$.

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: This question has been addressed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/5550/55622).

Answer (score 1):

Use the following characterisation of the rank of a matrix:

$$\operatorname{rank}A = \max \{n \in \mathbb N | \exists n \times n-\text{minor of } A \text{ with non-zero determinant}\}$$

Lets conclude (highly non-technical, but I guess you are familiar with $\varepsilon-\delta$-methods):

Give a matrix of rank $k$, you have some $k \times k$-minor with non-vanishing determinant (Let its absolute value be $>2\varepsilon$). Changing the matrix with the amount of some $\delta$, the $k \times k$-minor will also change with at most the amount of $\delta$. Provided $\delta$ is sufficiently small, by continuity of the determinant, you get that the determinant will change by only $\varepsilon$, hence is still positive. Hence we again find a $k \times k$-minor with non-vanishing determinant, thus the rank is at least $k$.

Comment: A Comment by the OP introduces a slight technical difficulty by asking for the operator norm to be used to define the balls about linear transformation $T$.